# Spring MVC - requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, model

When I type

```
http://localhost:1111/Quizat/test
```

in the URL, I do not get the login.jsp loaded but I get the "test is running" message printed on the console.

**My Controller:**

```
  @RequestMapping("/test")  
        public ModelAndView test(Model model) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("test is running");
            return new ModelAndView("login");
        }
```

**My dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass">
  <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
  </property>
<property name="prefix">
<value>/view/</value>
</property>    
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

I am working on a "dynamic web project". I have my login.jsp inside "WebContent/view/". Please do help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you get anything back in the browser? From the title of the question it looks like you are but could you post the stack?

Comment: I only get a 404 error with the message "Requested resource is not available"

Answer (score 0):

Define get mapping for /login.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you give me the snippet please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting "test is running", because your code is
`@RequestMapping("/test")`

Add following code -

```
<property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
```

Comment: I have that already in the snippet I have provided.
<property name="prefix">
<value>/view/</value>
</property>
My view folder is inside WebContent and not inside WEB-INF. So, i have given the path as /view/.